# how to search for a string in text file in C#

Tags: c#

I am working on text file..i want to know how to search for a string in text file and then perform the operations on that string.I have written a code but there is some problem with  "**if condition**",when the particular string comes,the control skips to the next line..it doesnot perform any operation on that string..
Below is the line from text file from which i am trying to find "MerchantNo:105838015" and then performing Substring operation on it to get only the number..There is a space in between the line..
MERCHANTNO:105838015                                                    AGENT CODE 00913

And this is the code:

```
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fldr);
        string line = null;

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            str = line.Trim().Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                if (str.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("MERCHANTNO:105838015"))
                {
                        //str = line.Split(' ');
                        string MNo1 = line.Substring(15, 23);
                        MNo = Convert.ToInt32(MNo1.ToString());
                }
                break;

            }

            //MessageBox.Show("Line is:" +line);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("MerchantNo is:" +MNo);
```

Please do say me what i have to do??

Comment: Why do you call substr with 15, 23?

Comment: Are you always looking for exactly that string: ...105838015 ? If you know this number a priori you do not need to parse and convert it to Int32 because you simply already know it. from your code you are looking for it hardcoded.

Comment: do you want to transform the hole stream? I don't know what operation you want to do - because your code says exactly what you describe: do nothing but check for "MERCHANTNO:105838015" and convert a substring from there to a int variable(?) MNo ... what *should* the code do?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear with my doubt..i am struggling in coding so if wrong do guide me..what i have to do is parse a textfile..i need to extract the exact records from the file and store it in database..and in the code above i have done hardcoding(to check) which is not a good to do..i need to extract the number based on text "MerchantNo" in the textfile and store it in database..likewise i have to do with other data also..hope now it is clear what i want to do..if not please do say me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that this is the problem:

```
if (str.ToString()...)
```

You're calling `ToString` on a string array. I suspect you meant:

```
if (str[i].ToUpper().Contains(...))
```

Having said that, it's not clear why you're then using the *line* for a substring - or why you're calling `MNo1.ToString()` when `MNo1` is already a string...

I would also recommend that you use:

```
if (str[i].IndexOf("MERCHANTNO:105838015",
                   StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
```

(or something similar, depending on what culture you want to use) rather than upper-casing each part.

You should also consider using a `foreach` loop instead of a `for` loop:

```
foreach (string part in line.Trim().Split(' '))
{
    if (part.IndexOf(...) > -1)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried using if (str[i].IndexOf("MERCHANTNO:105838015",
                   StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
but it is showing me an error that "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'"...and also i will try to do as you suggested for using foreach loop..

Comment: @Nazima: Apologies, I forgot to put the `> -1` bit in before - edited now.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use **Regular Expression** you can solve your problem quickly.
First of all read whole file in a variable and then apply your Regular Expression to that.

You can use **grouping** in your expression to get the number separately like below:

```
        int number = 0;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            string fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=.*MERCHANTNO:)(?<number>\d*)");
            var match = regex.Match(fileContent);
            if (match.Groups["number"].Success)
            {
                number = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups["number"].Value);
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("MerchantNo is:" + number);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing what this code supposed to do, but I guess you wanna make sure if the file contains this **merchantno**? You should use regex instead of substring juggling.

With text file:

```
MERCHANTNO:10583218015 AGENT CODE 00913
MERCHANO: 10421523838015 AGENT CODE 00913
Some teeeext MERCHANTNO:105838015 AGENT CODE 00913
Some text salalala ME
```

And code:

```
var regi = new Regex(@"MERCHANTNO:\s*([0-9]*)");
string need = "105838015";
bool found = false;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var match = regi.Match(line);
        if (match.Groups.Count == 2)
        {
            if (match.Groups[1].Value == need)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Found: {0}", found);
```

Maybe this is what you want? Fixme.

(string testing for value, to avoid 012 == 12 int parsing)